# Firefox reports that my KEY is Dead! But it doesn't tell me which

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Latest firefox, keydown events for document.body reports: keycode: 0, key: "Dead"

Ok, I know it is supposed to work this way. But why is it supposed to work this way?

Here's an example
    document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { // keypress doesn't work here
            console.log("KEY:::", e );
            stopPropagateEvent(e);
            return true;
        });

Pressing Dead Acute gives me e.key = "Dead", see doc at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key --- WTF!?! I know it is a composite key, I want the key!!!

Now the question is: How do I get the key (Acute in this example).

Comment: keycode is 192 for me

Comment: `code` contains the code of the pressed key, and you got the key, it's just "Dead".

Comment: @Chris G: The keycode is 0.

Comment: ...I don't know what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Teemu As it is a composite key, the key is Dead and the code is 0

Comment: @Chris G Doesn't matter. I want the code or the key of the composite key during composition.

Comment: Again: when I try your exact code in the latest firefox and press the dead acute, I get `´key: "Dead", keycode: 192`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/yLk1vdno/

Comment: I'm talking about [`event.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code), it's not numeric.

Comment: @ChrisG Nope: KEY::: 0 Dead 
keydown { target: body, key: "Dead", charCode: 0, keyCode: 0 } 
Firefox on Linux RH7, de_DE with composition keys enabled

Comment: Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61war0hd/) ...

Comment: @Teemu Thanks. I don't know what a fiddle is or how to operate it, but I guess you mean the untranslated code, which is "Backquote" in my case. It isn't It should be Dead Acute.

Comment: No, the the produced character (key) is `Dead`, and the code of the pressed key on the keyboard is coded as `Backquote`, that's all you can get. Notice, that `code`s are always the same, no matter which actual keboard layout you're using. This is the first time in history, when we finally can get reliable information about the keystrokes (in browsers), that wasn't possible before. Please read the above linked MDN article about `e.code`.

Comment: <html>
@Teemu The e.code uses US keyboard layout and isn't usable in any way. For example on my keyboard I get the same code for different keys:
<code>
KEY::: 192 ° Backquote

KEY::: 0 Dead Backquote
KEY::: 18 Alt AltLeft
KEY::: 173 - Slash
KEY::: 163 # Backslash
</code>
</html>

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've a scandic layout, and I still can rely on `code`, beacuse it tells you exactly which __key__ was pressed, it's not telling you which character was produced. `e.key` tells you that, and it is 100% correct, when it tells you "Dead", since no character was produced on that key stroke.

Comment: @Teemu Might work, yes. The "dead backquote" is indeed the backquote shifted. But it will be horribly complicated to get the real keys from that

Comment: The Acute character is produced on the next key stroke, but I admit it's not too simple to get some special characters, which can even be behind four separate key hits. If you've a more practical question of the usage, you could ask a new question about that. (As an example, to write a tilde (~), I've to hit CTRL + ALT + Rightbracket + space).

Comment: @Teemu Well, I need to send the keys to the back-end when I receive them java.awt.Robot will handle the composition. But with this crappy API I've decided to forget about composite keys and ignore them.
But thank you very much for the help!